# Do microcontroller's IO pins have to be on the same circuit as its power?

Tags: microcontroller, current, circuit-design

An electrical circuit needs to have a full loop for electricity to flow.
But if I had two programmable microcontrollers that were powered from their own batteries and were transmitting 2 analogue numbers too each other through 2 wires (one for each direction) then would the circuit still work?
I ask this as if, for example, there was more energy flowing from left too right then from right too left then there would be more electrons on the right side then the left side.

[image]
The two big grey squares are the microcontrollers and the red arrows show the direction of flow of electricity.

Ultimately would this work and if not, how could I achieve the same results with as few wires as possible?

Comment: ‘Ground’ is just a reference / return plane, not necessarily 0 volts. But we treat it as if it is 0 volts.

Comment: If your fine with extra parts, look into galvanicly isolated AC signalling like ethernet uses.

Comment: There *is* wireless communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Without a common signal ground you cannot transmit an analogue signal from one side to the other. Note that I've swapped the battery terminals on the right hand side.

> *how could I achieve the same results with as few wires as possible?*

You could transmit the digitized versions of the analogue signals via radio = zero connection wires. Or, you could transmit the digitized analogue signal optically or magnetically. Simplicity and reliability = wires.

Comment: Thank you! I assume this would work fine if there was a web of microcontrollers where not all of them connect to every other microcontrollers?

Comment: @GreenJon902 As long as all their grounds are connected together. If they're not, you need a different sort of signalling.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a common ground between the two devices (commonly used, simple) or some sort of differential-to-single ended transmission scheme.

Comment: Even differential schemes normally require a common ground, as the receivers have a limited voltage range. An exception is when there is galvanic isolation as provided by Ethernet.

Comment: There are now stock integrated *galvanic isolation amplifiers* with a common mode rejection in the 100dB ballpark. I seem to remember dU/dt restrictions with discrete assemblies of (InAmp based?) *galvanically connected isolation amplifiers* - working otherwise to (few) hundreds of Volts between grounds.